# PrimeNG p-table - Cannot push item (row) into 'selection''

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, p-table

I am using Angular 9, PrimeNG p-table component.

```
<p-table [value]="cars" selectionMode="multiple" dataKey="id" [(selection)]="selection">
```

So, what is a problem.

**I have 5 rows and for each row I have checkbox. When I select some row or rows, 'selection' is populated and checkboxes are 'checked' but when I manually pust item to 'selection' list - I can't see checked rows until I click on some row checkbox.**

Reason why I want to do this is because I have input fields in row/s so when I change input value, I would call a method that will automatically preselect that row as 'checked' in checkbox.

Comment: how do you push a selection can you share a code with us ?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is that I did push in wrong way

Wrong:
this.selection.push(item);

Good:
[...this.selection,item]